# Hibernate Many To Many relationship with predicate on child table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to implement a query with Criteria which is going to return an object of type A containing a list of B object's.

The tables are as follows:

A -> B <- C (B is the join table)

What I want to do is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON ...
LEFT JOIN C ON ...
WHERE A.COLUMN_1 = 'SMTH'
AND A.COLUMN_2 = 'AMTH'
AND C.COLUMN3 != 'HELLO
AND C.COLUMN4 != 'BYE';


    


public Optional<A> method(String firstParam, String secondParam, Boolean thirdParam) {

        Preconditions.checkNotNull(firstParam);
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(secondParam);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<A> ACriteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);
        Root<A> ARoot = ACriteriaQuery.from(A.class);
        ACriteriaQuery.select(ARoot);

        Predicate secondParamPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(ARoot.get("columnOne"), secondParam);
        Predicate firstParamPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(ARoot.get("columnTwo"), firstParam);

        predicates.add(secondParamPredicate);
        predicates.add(firstParamPredicate);

        if (thirdParam == null || thirdParam) {

            Join<A, B> ABJoin = ARoot.join("B", JoinType.LEFT);
            Predicate p1 = criteriaBuilder.notEqual(ABJoin.get("column3"), "hello");
            predicates.add(p1);

        }

        Predicate finalPredicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        ACriteriaQuery.where(finalPredicate).distinct(Boolean.TRUE);

        TypedQuery<A> query = entityManager.createQuery(ACriteriaQuery);
        List<A> As = query.getResultList();

        if (As.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.absent();
        }
        if (As.size() > 1) {
            throw new NonUniqueResultException();
        }
        return Optional.of(As.get(0));

    }
```

I thought that this query was going to return an object of type A with a filtered list of objects of type B based on the two last conditions. But in fact it is returning a list of objects A each containing a list of B.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: How do you execute the query? Please show some code

Comment: I updated the issue

Comment: You cannot filter the content of a ToMany relationship with a query

Comment: Shouldn't the criteriaBuilder.notEqual(ABJoin.get("column3"), "hello") do that?

Comment: No the join is just used to create the where clause for selecting A

Comment: And how would I achieve my goal? Any idea?

Comment: That's not possible with Entities